# React app using msal-react, how to automatically authenticate user

Tags: msal.js

I'm working on a react app where the pages can be used both by authenticated and anonymous users. The pages show more features for the authenticated users.

If a user previously has signed in and revists the website, I want the user to be automatically authenticated, and am struggling to achieve this.

I'm using redirect methods because I don't believe popup is working well on phones (is that assumption correct?).

I have tried storing the homeAccountId in local storage and use that to get the account used and then calling login in the msal instance. I also set up a `addEventCallback` and listen for `EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS` which I use to set some internal state about the logged in user.

I have tried using `MsalAuthenticationTemplate` but strangely this doesn't invoke a login. I have also tried to detect if this is a "first run" and then invoking the login, but that doesn't work all the time. Sometime I get a SSO error indicating I should provide a login_hint or sid which is not possible because I use B2C.

If I don't do anything the user can click the login button and if the user has a valid cookie with B2C the user is logged in without providing credentials which is a strange behavior for the user because my website indicate the user is not authenticated (and show no logout button).

So I can't really get this to work and are wondering if somebody has a concept for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout the [msal-react samples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-react-samples) which all demonstrate the behavior you're looking for. The `MsalAuthenticationTemplate` would be the recommended way to do this and if you're still having issues getting this to work after reviewing the samples I would recommend opening an [issue on our repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues) with code snippets so we can take a closer look at what's going on.

Also using `localStorage`, if you're not already, would help to maintain application state between browser sessions. `sessionStorage` is the default.

As for B2C not asking for credentials; server state is separate from client state. You can be signed in on the server without the application knowing about it. Until your application makes a request to the B2C server your application will show that a user is not signed in. If a session already exists on the server when you make a login request, the server may redirect you back to your application without asking for credentials again.

Comment: None of the linked samples appear to demonstrate auto-login functionality.

Comment: @AndrewMcLachlan Spin up one of the samples and navigate directly to the /profile route. You'll be asked to sign in via redirect or popup depending on which sample you choose to use.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. Which sample are you referring to, Thomas? When I go to /profile it doesn't do any automatic redirecting, I just have to click "Sign in" in the navbar. I am using ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial-main and in the 3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c project, though I've checked others and am not seeing this behavior there either.

Comment: @jdempcy Any of the samples located [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-react-samples). I'm not sure what the samples in the Azure-Samples repo demonstrate, those are not managed by the MSAL.js team.